# Watch external processes for read/write events in C?

Tags: c, linux, events, process, watch

Is it possible to watch external process by its pids for read/write events? In particular I want to write a program which counts bytes an external process has written to `stdout`, `stderr` or `FILE*`. Desired platform is Linux. Note: I cannot change source code of target processes.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own kernel module, just make a simple shell that will intercept file operations, or make an dynamic library that would substitute some stdlib calls and call external process with LD_PRELOAD=your_lib.so.

Comment: How do I intercept file operations by shell?

Answer (score 0):

To see each write as it occurs:

```
strace -ewrite -p$PID
```

To see a sum of bytes written when the process ends:

```
strace -ewrite -p$PID 2>&1 | { while read; do set $REPLY; n=$_; [ $n -gt 0 ] && let count+=$n; done; echo $count; }
```

The above assume that process $PID already runs; note that only writes after `strace` started are counted. To account from the start of $PROCESS, start it with `strace -ewrite $PROCESS` instead.